# Populate a value in combobox dynamicly

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a form where user picks a Item# and gets info for the selected Item. This form got enhanced by adding another filter, using a combobox control, to select a 'warehouse'.

I could use a lookup for the warehouse(the list is huge) to chosse a 'warehouse' but what am trying to do to query warehouse on Item# value and populate into combobox.

Tried to attached a screen shot, unfotunately, the system doesn't let me do it.  If I need to put more details, please let me know.

Is it doable?

Comment: You need some more detail. What platform is this for - web, desktop app, etc.? What is the backend?

Comment: You have to be more concrete than this. What field are in your form and what are the sequence of events? Upload the image somewhere else, then provide the link.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do this with a temporary table. Create one in AOT, and declare it as global variable in your form.

When Item (datasource field or design control, choose what's more accurate for you) is modified, just delete table content, and fill it at your needs.

In the control lookup method, call temporary table lookup method, i.e. "static void lookup(TMPTable _tmpTable)". Do a SysTableLookup, with a standard query over TMPtable, but it's important to use QueryBuildDataSource.setCursor(_tmpTable) (I don't remember now where was method setCursor() in Query or QueryRun, search for it a bit).